# How to use varnish with nginx as SSL terminator and with http to https forwarding

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, wordpress, varnish

I have installed varnish and nginx and secured my website with lets encrypt SSL. I tested varnish against nginx cgi cache and i have found out that varnish is a bit faster in my use case (wordpress). So i need some help on how to use nginx for SSL termination with varnish and how to forward http to https as my website is https only. I am running ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Anyone? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below lines in /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if ( (req.http.host ~ "^(?i)www.yourdomain.com" || req.http.host ~ "^(?i)www.yourdomain.com") && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") 
  {
           return (synth(750, ""));
  }
  }

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = "https://www.yourdomain.com" + req.url;
    return(deliver);
  }
  }
```